# array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array during add variable to existing array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array to pass from `controller` to `view`.

```
$data['message'] = $data = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId, $optParamsGet2);
$data['mail'] = $mail;
```

while adding `$data['mail'] = $mail`, it showing the `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`.

I need to render both `$message` and `$mail` in the view. How can i?

Comment: Where is your array_merge code

Comment: please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Error**

> array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

**Where it occurs**

The line where you are generating the view for your mail:

E.g: `view('greetings', $data);`

or

`Mail::send('greetings', $data, function ($message) {});`

**Why it occurs**

When passing information to a view, `$data` should be an array with key/value pairs. Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as `<?php echo $key; ?>`

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#passing-data-to-views

In your case, `$data` is NOT an array, hence the error.

**How to Fix**

Make sure your `$data` variable is an array when being passed to the above examples.

Comment: thanks @Mysteryos. I'm dealing with gmail-api and it provides me a pretty good well formed nested array

Comment: Can you update your question with the full code brief? It would help. Also an error trace dump as well.